# Convert date and time in string to timestamp

Tags: python, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a set of CSV's that all got loaded with a date field like: `Sunday August 7, 2022 6:26 PM GMT`

I'm working on a way to take this date/time, and convert it to a proper timestamp in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`

In Python, I've tried something like below to return a proper timestamp.

```py
def convert_to_timestamp(date_string):
    date_format = "%A %B %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z"
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)
    return timestamp
```

...but it keeps coming back with errors similar to below.

```
ValueError: time data 'Sunday August 7,2022 6:26 PM GMT' does not match format '%A %B %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z'
```

How would I convert this field in a CSV to the required format using Python?

Comment: I think it might be the missing space between `7,` and `2022` in `date_string`

Comment: Can you edit the first sentence of your question? You say the CSVs got loaded with a date field like `Sunday August 7, 2022 6:26 PM GMT` but the error message shows the format is different (no space before the year).

Answer (score 0):

##### CHECK THE EDITS

The function looks good. I think the main cause of this issue is the comma. Try this instead:

```py
def convert_to_timestamp(date_string):
    date_string = date_string.replace(",", "")  # Remove the comma after the day
    date_format = "%A %B %d %Y %I:%M %p %Z"
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)
    return timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

`.strftime()` formats the string to make it look like what you described; it's optional.

Let me know how it goes!

**Edit:** A commenter said that in the error message, the string the function receives has no space between the comma and the year date, which is different from the input you mentioned in the question above.

If your input is like the one in the error, then this is how you'll write the function:

```py
def convert_to_timestamp(date_string):
    date_string = date_string.replace(",", " ")  # Replace the comma after the day with a space
    date_format = "%A %B %d %Y %I:%M %p %Z"
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)
    return timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

**Last edit:** Alas, all of this is not needed, assuming the input in the error message. Just remove the space in the formatting of your original function. The edit above is just a roundabout way of doing the same thing. I'll leave all versions of this function up just in case something doesn't work. Here's the updated function (with `.strftime()` for better formatting):

```py
def convert_to_timestamp(date_string):
    date_format = "%A %B %d,%Y %I:%M %p %Z"
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)
    return timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Comment: Removing the comma will give `Sunday August 72022 6:26 PM GMT` which seems like it might cause a problem.

Comment: Nope. You are not removing the space after the comma. I also tested this code.

Comment: But OP's stack trace shows that there is no space after the comma: `ValueError: time data 'Sunday August 7,2022 6:26 PM GMT' does not match format '%A %B %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z'`. To be fair, the question is confusing, because the date format that OP describes in the first sentence is not the actual date format as demonstrated by the stack trace.

Comment: oh my god. I just ran OP's original code with this string `Sunday August 7, 2022 6:26 PM GMT` as the input and it also worked. When I ran the one without the space, it gave the mentioned error. Could OP have passed the wrong string in the first place, but wrote it correctly in the question?

Assuming OP's input is without space, this should be the fix: `date_string = date_string.replace(",", " ")`

Comment: @slothrop I edited my original post to match both cases. Thank you so much for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

The format you're supplying to `strptime` is not correct.
For the format to work, `Sunday August 7,2022 6:26 PM GMT` needs to be `Sunday August 7, 2022 6:26 PM GMT`.

Notice there's no space **after** `7,`. This is observed from the error you're seeing.

If you don't own the CSV or can't control where it's coming from, you could change the `date_format` to `"%A %B %d,%Y %I:%M %p %Z"`. I only removed the space after `%d,`.

Here's the full snippet.

```py
from datetime import datetime

def convert_to_timestamp(date_string):
    date_format = "%A %B %d,%Y %I:%M %p %Z"
    # Parse date_string into a datetime.
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)
    # Convert into desired format.
    return timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Outputs - 2022-08-07 18:26
    print(convert_to_timestamp('Sunday August 7,2022 6:26 PM GMT'))
```

I just ran the same example in a repl [here](https://www.online-python.com/BXuqQnk3zD).

Answer (score 0):

There are several date parsers which will accept many formats:

```
from dateutil import parser

d = "Sunday August 7,2022 6:26 PM GMT"

d2 = parser.parse(d)

print(d2)
```

gives

```
2022-08-07 18:26:00+00:00
```

+00:00 reflects GMT